# select max count HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

Please can anyone help me converting this to HQL?

```
 SELECT COUNT(customerId) AS `cnt` 
 FROM property
 GROUP BY customerId 
 ORDER BY `cnt` 
 DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(customerId) AS `cnt`
FROM property GROUP BY customerId ORDER BY `cnt` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Can be write in the same way in HQL.

Important thing is: how you have mapped POJO.

So I suppose you have a class Property where you have a property customerId.

So a possible your query can be:

```
SELECT COUNT(P.customerId) AS `cnt`
FROM Property P
GROUP BY P.customerId
ORDER BY `cnt` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Finally I advice you to rewrite your SQL query in this way to get the MAX value:

```
SELECT MAX(t.cnt)
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(customerId) as cnt
    FROM property) t
```